# Why is "colonel" pronounced "kernel"?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why does the word *colonel* (as in military rank) have such a strange spelling compared to how it's pronounced (or vice versa, although I don't know how you would pronounce that)?

Comment: And don't get me started on the British and Canadian pronunciation of *lieutenant* ;-)

Comment: @ghoppe, but only in the army and the air force; not the navy.

Comment: Sub-lieutenant Hooper, you are on a charge!

Comment: is it only me or do you hear "kernel" when this word is spoken in the US?

Comment: I'm not coluite clear what your coluestion is. Do you find the spelling coluirky somehow?

Comment: @BrianHooper, how would a person of that naval rank be addressed by a colleague in their army?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit I really couldn't say. The only forces people I spoke to regularly where RAF. I suspect Tim Lymington isn't altogether in agreement with my comment in any case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It comes from Italian military manuals, and the English spelling preserves the Italian form, *colonnello*. Two pronunciations coexisted; the *r* prevailed in English. Spanish took both the spelling and pronunciation: *coronel*.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=colonel

Comment: Collenella meaning 'column', i.e. column of troops. So a colonel is a commander of a column.

Comment: It'd be better to say that though it was originally spelt *coronel* and retains that pronunciation, the spelling was *artificially* changed during 16th-century spelling reform.

Comment: The Italian word for _colonel_ is _colonnello_, which comes from the Italian word _colonna_ (_column_), which comes from the Latin _columna_. (My first language is Italian, so you can trust me on that **;-)**.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Perhaps it was different in the 16th Century?

Comment: @Jay: the word was _colonnello_ also in the 16th Century.

Answer (score 3):

As reported from the NOAD:

> ORIGIN middle 16th Century: from obsolete French *coronel* (earlier form of *colonel*), from Italian *colonnello* (column of soldiers) from *colonna* (column) from Latin *columna*. The form *coronel*, source of the modern pronunciation, was usual until the middle 17th Century.

The word is pronounced in a strange way because it kept the old pronunciation, while the word changed spelling.

Comment: why change the spelling?

Comment: @user4951, See my answer below.