# Why is "gauge" spelled with a 'u'?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I was rather old before I realized "gauge" is pronounced (and sometimes spelt) "gage".  The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=gauge&searchmode=none) doesn't reveal too much:

> mid-15c., from Anglo-Fr. gauge (mid-14c.), from O.N.Fr. gauger, from gauge "gauging rod," 
>   perhaps from Frank. galgo "rod, pole for measuring" (cf. O.N. gelgja "pole, perch," O.H.G. 
>   galgo, English gallows) ... The figurative use is from 1580s. As a noun, "fixed standard of measure," early 15c. (surname Gageman is early 14c.), from O.N.Fr. gauge "gauging rod." Meaning "instrument for measuring" is from 1680s.

Is it just a quirk, or is there a deeper reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a hard one. I'll list here what I can say about it so far, but I don't have any single definite source.

You provided the relevant etymonline link for the English etymology. I will add that dictionaries list *gage* as a possible alternative spelling of *gauge*.

The Middle English *gauge* comes from the Old French *gauge* (n.) /*gauger* (v.), which correspond to the Modern French *jauge* / *jauger*. In turn, none of my French dictionaries has a definite etymology for *gauge*. The [Littré](https://web.archive.org/web/20100527063025/http://francois.gannaz.free.fr:80/Littre/accueil.php) says (translated and heavily summarized):

> Could come from Latin *aequalificare* or *qualificare*. Definitely related to (and influenced by) the Old French *jale/jalaie* (wooden measuring pail) and *gallon* (), which themselves come from a series of Late Latin roots including *galida* (from Latin *galletum*). Also related to the German *eichen*.

So, it is seen that *gauge*, at the time it was imported from Old French into Middle English, coexisted with a lot of words of similar meaning and close spelling. Thus, probably *gauge* took its writing from *gauge* and its pronunciation from a mixture of those words (*gauge*, *jale*, *gallon*).

---

Regarding the issue of whether the initial consonant is a soft or hard *g*, it is funny enough to note that while the English word, with it hard *g*, comes from the Old French (which had soft *g*), the Modern French uses *gauge* as a nautical term, imported from the English, with its hard initial *g*.

Comment: +1 - Two comments: 1/ About the pronunciation shift from Old French "au" to English /eɪ/: there is another example in Fr. *sauf* => *safe* /seɪf/ 2/ About the etymology. Source "Dic hist Lang Franç, Robert 2vols" 1992: Germanic peoples used 2 perpendicular graduated rods to measure (to gauge) the volume of containers. A rod was named *galgo* (plural *galga*).  This is still visible in the name *gallow* (perpendicular beams) and their Germanic cognates *Galga* (Swedish, Danish) and *Galgen* (German) all of which mean gallows.  *Gallon* itself is a volume *gauged* with these *galga*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some people pronounce "aunt" as "aint", so there may be some forcing together of two formerly separated sounds in French that occurred after the words were borrowed — just a guess: the original sounds in Old French might provide a guide.

Answer (score 0):

To add, more of a comment that was posted in the wrong place (edited, still can't delete); this is heavily on other topics.

It might be like the word "colonel", where the modern English term is pronounced "CUR-nul", taking from old French versions "coronel" and "coronella", but where the word in writing takes after the earlier Italian form "colonella".

"Gage" also derives from French. Like "colonel", the pronunciation keeps to the historical French while the spelling suggests it should be otherwise.

A factor in the non-literal reading of such words might be regional and colloquial pronunciations tending to change over time. It may be similar to the way some people (or the majority of people in some social or geographical enclaves) pronounce "aunt" as "ant".

I also think to my theory of pronunciation and spelling of British English becoming corrupted and evolving to better fit modern usage after English-speakers migrated from Europe to America; the different dialects and ways of word enunciation heard in U.S. could be imagined that they morphed from British accents, even though they sound very different.

Comment: Hi J.J, welcome to ELU! If you want to put your post in the comments, click on 'the add a comment' box and cut 'n paste into there. If you ever want to delete your post, underneath each posts there's three buttons 'share' 'edit' 'flag'. Underneath your own posts there's a fourth tab that says 'delete' If you click on that the whole post will get deleted [- but you personally will still be able to see it in pink on the relevant page] The way the site functions won't let you delete via 'edits'  :)

Comment: @Araucaria Don't forget that commenting anywhere needs 50 rep.

Comment: @J.J. Unfortunately this isn't an answer to the question as asked. You may be able to mould it into a question about *colonel,* and possibly even [answer that question yourself](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Do take a look at the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the rest of the Help pages to see more of how Stack Exchange works as a Question-and-Answer site rather than a forum.

Comment: @AndrewLeach J.J. nobly tried to delete their post using the edit function and deleting the words, which I assume would just leave an empty post or one with a minimum number of characters or something. Edit note which JJ left was: 'this is really a comment'. Perhaps there's something you could do to help?

Comment: It's too long to convert to a comment. The best solution to preserve (and expand) the information is to find [a related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/whats-the-deal-with-colonel) and add an answer there, taking care not to duplicate existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

Frequently, the "l" in the diphtongue "al" before a consonant, or sometimes "ol", becomes an "u". This is owing to the pronunciation of those sounds, phonetical relaxing and other linguistical phenomena like these.