# "strain gauge" or "gage"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography

When referring to a device that measures tensile or compressive force, is the correct spelling *strain gauge* or *strain gage*?

I realize that [in general](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36706/why-is-gauge-spelled-with-a-u) *gage* is an archaic spelling of the word *gauge*, but which spelling should be used in this compound?  (Context is an engineering dissertation on signal processing)

- [Google Ngram viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strain+gage%2Cstrain+gauge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: http://www.efunda.com/designstandards/sensors/strain_gages/strain_gage_theory.cfm

Comment: Here is the webpage you have mentioned before
https://www.omega.com/en-us/resources/strain-gages
In address, it's 'gages', as well as in the shop.
But, in the text it's 'gauges' exlusively right now Interesting, but I prefer 'gauges'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "gauge", whether it's a strain or a fuel gauge.  Or a narrow gauge railroad, or a 12-gauge shotgun.

In my personal opinion it should be "gage" in all these cases because it is definitely not spelled the way it is pronounced.  But who cares what I think?

"gauge" is the correct spelling in most cases, but "gage" does get used in technical situations, as Dictionary.com indicates.

Here's [Dictionary.com's version](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gauge?s=ts). The spelling "gage" is an occasional variant, but mainly for technical use (see [gage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gage?s=t)). Gage is largely an archaic spelling, and in one archaic use, a gage is "something, as a glove, thrown down by a medieval knight in token of challenge to combat."

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought should be the correct spelling from my research, but a lot of professional sources use the other spelling.  e.g. http://www.vishaypg.com/micro-measurements/

Comment: Unless it's a greengage, in which case, it's definitely a gage.

Comment: -1 Please cite your sources, especially as your answer is contrary to your "personal opinion".

Comment: @Kris, my source is the dictionary.  Does this really need a source citation? Nevertheless, I've now cited it, so you can remove your downvote if you like. As for my personal opinion, it's a matter of spelling reform, like wishing "through" were spelled "thru", since English pronunciation of many words has evolved, while the spelling of them has not.

Comment: You may not have noticed but the down vote is not for not citing the source but for **"gauge" is the correct spelling in all cases.** See also, the link I provided in comment at OP.

Comment: I see your point, @Kris.  Modified answer to correspond. Thanks for your attention to this detail, especially on this five year old question.

Comment: @SimonB ... or a [greens gage](https://accuproducts.com/index.php/accugage-19.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually companies whose business is the manufacturing of what I have always known as gauges and whose company name includes the word "Gage". What I have found is that there are some who believe gage is correct. I'm sticking with gauge. Gage is just wrong to me.

Comment: We can use comments to post personal opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a testing lab and we generally use gage when referring to the strain sensor .. gauge is used as in "hydraulic pressure gauge"  however both spellings have been used here frequently in the 20 years I have worked here. No one has said we must use one spelling in preference over the other with reference to strain sensors..

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens--if not hundreds--of "gage" manufacturers and vendors. Moreover, there are thousands of technical documents using the term "gage" to denote specialized measuring equipment.

Here is an excerpt from the Omega.com "Introduction to Strain Gages" article:

"A strain gage (sometimes referred to as a Strain gauge) is a sensor whose resistance varies with applied force; It converts force, pressure, tension, weight, etc., into a change in electrical resistance which can then be measured. When external forces are applied to a stationary object, stress and strain are the result. Stress is defined as the object's internal resisting forces, and strain is defined as the displacement and deformation that occur."