# "gauging interest" or "gaging interest"?

Tags: differences, orthography, pronunciation-respelling

Which is the proper spelling?

"I am just gaging interest"
"I am just gauging interest"

Google searching is giving me inconsistent results.
Also: If the answer is "gaging", why does the 'u' get dropped?

Comment: What happens when you look it up [in a dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gage) rather than as a phrase in Google? Google just catalogues other people's [mis-]uses.

Comment: I believe you answered part of my question by revealing that "gage" and "gauge" are actually two different words. However I'd like to know more about the present-continuous form of these words.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128096/strain-gauge-or-gage

Comment: Noah Webster dropped the *u* in *gauge* so that the [American] spelling matched the pronunciation.

Comment: ***Difference Between Gage and Gauge***: 

http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-gage-and-vs-gauge/

Comment: @Josh61 thanks for the useful clarifications

Comment: Can one of the closers explain what's wrong with my question? I'm pretty sure I followed every rule and guideline.

Comment: I'd rather this question get deleted if the mods don't find it useful, rather than keep it around with a giant badge of shame saying "your question sucks". I think it's a very useful question to have on this site.

Comment: This question has been visited by approximately 99,000 EL&U site visitors despite having been closed for the past seven years on grounds of "Please include the research you've done..." Since so many people are interested in this particular topic, can we agree that it's a question of broad interest and reopen it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Simplified Spelling Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Spelling_Board) of the early 1900s in the United States made *gauge* one of its targets in the early 1920s, urging the replacing of *au* with *a* to yield *gage*. From Simplified Spelling Board, [*Handbook of Simplified Spelling*](http://archive.org/stream/handbookofsimpli00simprich/handbookofsimpli00simprich_djvu.txt) (1920):

> **Principles Adopted**
>
> Its [the Board's] recommendations, accordingly, have been based 
>   on the following principles :
>
> 1) When current usage offers a choice of spellings, to adopt the shortest and simplest. EXAMPLES : blest, not blessed ; catalog, not catalogue; center, not centre; check, not cheque or checque; **gage, not gauge**; gram, not gramme; honor, not honour; license, not licence; maneuver, not manoeuvre; mold, not mould; plow, not plough; quartet, not quartette; rime, not rhyme; tho, not though; traveler, not traveller.

However, Cornell Kimball, "[Common Misspellings and Dictionary Alternatives](http://spellingsociety.org/uploaded_journals/j26-journal-1420110730.pdf)," in *Journal of the Simplified Spelling Society* (1999/2000) reports that adoption of *gage* has been uneven:

> **4. Comments on Internet findings**
>
> *Minuscule, gauge, misspell*
>
> For these words there are also dictionary-given alternative spellings.
>
> ...
>
> With *gauge*, the dictionary-accepted variant is *gage*, but the situation is different from that of miniscule. In certain fields (science, engineering), *gage* is the more commonly used, that is, it is the 'standard' spelling. In the figures above, I have simply not counted *gage* one way or the other (by using the criteria I mentioned in the previous paragraph, *gage* would be listed with the 'other than standard forms'). This search noted *gauge* occurred 8879 times for *gauge* and *guage* 2211 times. I computed its misspelling rate from those two: 2211/(8879+2211) = 20%. (I also found *gage* occurred 1848 times during the same period, but did not add that to either of the totals.)

Of course, *gage* has shown up as an alternative to *gauge* for centuries, but an Ngram chart of *gauging* (blue line) versus *gaging* (red line) over the period 1800–2008 shows a major rise in the incidence of *gaging* starting around 1903 (near the beginning of the [simplified spelling movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_reform), and then fading in the mid-1960s as that movement began to lose steam:

[image]

As a copy editor, if I saw *gaging* in a manuscript, I would peremptorily change it to *gauging*, regardless of what the subject of the article or book was, unless house style specifically expressed a preference for the variant *gaging*.

Comment: Thanks! The only improvement i'd recommend is that I'd put the answer to my question "gauging interest" in a short phrase at the top.

Answer (score 3):

gauging is UK spelling

gaging is given as an alternative US spelling here.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gage

Comment: I believe gage is the wrong word for my question. You "gauge interest", I don't think that you "gage interest"

Comment: If you are English then no. According to Merriam-Webster which I quoted (and is a respected American dictionary) you could 'gage interest'.  Like you however I much prefer 'gauge'.