# Why "pastime" but not "passtime"?

Tags: etymology, differences, orthography, is-it-a-word, historical-change

> **pastime** *n.*  An activity that occupies one's spare time pleasantly: *Sailing is her favorite pastime.* [[TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pastime)

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pastime) says that it is from *pass* + *time*:

> late 15c., *passe tyme* "recreation, diversion, amusement, sport," from *pass* (v.) + *time* (n.). Formed on model of Middle French *passe-temps* (15c.), from *passe*, imperative of *passer* "to pass" + *temps* "time."

So, why did one "s" drop (Did it drop? Maybe never dropped) or why not double "s"? (i.e. Why not "passtime"?) Is there any historical or orthographic reason?

---

**Further details:**

I think *pastime* is often confused with *past time* and *passtime*. I'm not sure if *passtime* is a word but I see a significant amount of usage in written works [in Google Books]. (Is it an incorrect usage in every case? Can it be a dialectal spelling?)

*Pass time* means to spend time doing something. [Even, *pastime* was used as a verb in the past.]

It gets even more complicated when there are noun forms of *passtime* and *pass time* with different meanings.

I see the usage of "passtime" as the amount of time passed in technical contexts. Also "pass time" is used in this sense in specific contexts. For example:

> In road transport, the time that elapses between the moment when the leading vehicle of a column passes a given point and the moment when the last vehicle passes the same point. [[TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pass+time)

<sub>**Note:** I'm aware that English spelling has a lot of irregularities but we are here to discuss the finer details of the language. I have a good case with details and I believe there might be hints from the history.</sub>

<sub>For example, a similar question: [Why is "gauge" spelled with a 'u'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36706/why-is-gauge-spelled-with-a-u)</sub>

Comment: I can't think of  any English word with a double 's' before a 't'.

Comment: English spelling is frequently irregular since it developed by conventions over time. In technical usage, I frequently see elapsed time.

Comment: Where do you see a significant amount of usage of *passtime* outside the meaning of *time it takes to pass a vehicle*?

Comment: @CarSmack: Google Books.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well a lot of those uses do refer to technical uses. There is also 'pass time' referring to the 'time of a (military) pass [permission to leave base]; most other uses are a combination of the verb *pass* with the direct object *time.* Similar to *kill time* or *spend time.* I thought you meant you saw a lot of spellings of pastime with two esses (passtime or pass(-)time). I didn't see any instances of *passtime,* but maybe I didn't look far enough.

Comment: @user6697:  crosstown, misstate, newsstand

Answer (score 2):

I  think this has something to do with spellings such as

full, but hopeful, grateful and similar adjectives, and also fulfil BrE, AmE fulfill

till, but until

all, but almost, always and similar words.

Unfortunately I have never seen a spelling rule that covers the whole phenomenon and tries to give an explanation. It seems that two identical consonants are reduced to one consonant in compound words, just to reduce the effort of writing. But whether this is a general rule or a phenomenon found only in some compound words that is a problem I have never looked into more closely.

This is what I have found on the Internet

http://www.howtospell.co.uk/adding-all-till-full

Comment: Interesting. An even more similar example is "full, but fulfill" since here the dropped double consonant is in the middle of the word.

Answer (score -1):

Agree, doesn't pay to apply conventional logic to a language that evolves through usage, influences, inclusions, and meanings that weaken, as well as having its own internal logic that allows exceptions and standalones. Especially English.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?