# Why is "sergeant" pronounced "sargent"?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I remember when I first came across this word, I thought it was pronounced /'sɜr-dʒint/ (SER-jeent).  Now I am curious as to why the first syllable is pronounced /sar/ rather than /sɜr/.  I looked at the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sergeant&searchmode=none), and found that the word has always had either *sir* or *ser* at the beginning, never *sar*.  To top that off, *sergeant* comes from the Old French *sergent*, from Latin *servientem* meaning *serving*, the same root word that we get the word *servant* from.  To my knowledge, *servant* has never been pronounced /'sar-vənt/.  Why and since when has *sergeant* been pronounced *sargent*?

Comment: Why do the British pronounce *lieutenant* "leftenant"? Or clerk "clark"?

Comment: @Robusto: I don't know.

Comment: @Daniel δ: I don't care! :)

Comment: @Danielδ - they're from the French. The British are known for both their intricate knowledge of other languages and the efforts they are prepared to go to in order to respect and honour their French neighbours.

Comment: *Clerk* pronounced "clark", *Berkeley* pronounced "Barklee", *derby* pronounced "darbee" and *sergeant* pronounced "sarjent" all seem to be part of the same sound shift. I don't know the cause of it, and I don't know why *sergeant* is the only one pronounced this way in the U.S.

Comment: Why is *colonel* pronounced "kernel"?

Comment: @rajah9 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/whats-the-deal-with-colonel

Comment: Same reason ... that colonel is "kernel" Old words that were once pronounced in a different way, that evolved into a different argot use, but kept their archaic spelling. English seems chock-full of hundreds of these crumpets.

Comment: Why  "clerk" and "derby" are pronounced "klurk" and "durby," but "sergeant" as "sargent" in the U.S.?

Comment: @PeterShor Derby is pronounced 'darby' except by people with local accents from the Durbyshire peak district who pronounce it 'Durby'. Apparently a similar thing applies to Shrewsbury/Shrowsbury/Shrewsbry/Salop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the [Naval Historical Center](http://www.history.navy.mil/browse-by-topic/organization-and-administration/ranks/naval-traditions-names-of-rank/enlisted-ranks/sergeant.html):

> The English borrowed the word "sergeant" from the French in about the
>   Thirteenth Century. They spelled it several different ways and
>   pronounced it both as SARgent and SERgeant. The latter was closer to
>   the French pronunciation. The SARgeant pronunciation became the most
>   popular, however, so that when the Nineteenth Century dictionary
>   writers agreed that the word should be spelled "sergeant" they could
>   not change the popular pronunciation. Thus, we say SARgeant while the
>   French and others say SERgeant.

Comment: See person and parson, perhaps from different dialects of early French, but think of how Dickens represented -er- in the speech of some of his characters and how some upper class English speakers might refer to the squire as the squaar, hence the squarson, being both squire and parson.

Comment: a deeply opinionated and anecdotal take though it may be, I personally think "SARgent" sounds more "English" than "SERgent" would, which I conjecture is why it stuck.

Answer (score 6):

The digraph <er> represented /ɜːr/, which became opener /ɑː(r)/. As the sound shifted, so the spelling shifted to <ar> in many words. Folks have kept the old spelling especially in the case of their names and place names, so we have a mismatch between the spelling and the expected sound. In other cases, we have two spelling versions: *derby* vs *darby, clerk* vs *clarke, Hervey* vs *Harvey, merchant* vs *marchant, farmer* vs *fermor*; etc. Most of this is from 
Jack Windsor Lewis's [Derby and Similar Words](http://www.yek.me.uk/Blog.html#blog449).  This mismatch (*sergeant* vs *sar-*) is not unique to *sergeant*. You can find more examples in that post from JWL. Check his [Grapho-Phonemic mis-cordinations](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive16.html#blog153).

Comment: Can you explain some of those things right here? The link is great, but it'd be nice to have an idea in case the link goes away.